# White and red lines across the top of the screen with 13.04 on an Intel machine

Tags: 13.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on an Intel PC which had no OS on it at the time of installation.  The OS looks great and I'm really looking forward to getting stuck in with it, but I've got a display issue I can't resolve.  There is a series of white and red lines running from left to right at the top of the screen. Is this a known issue that someone can advise me on?

Thanks in advance,
D

I don't know how to upload an image of it.  Sorry.

Comment: now you can upload an image

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not an ubuntu issue! It's sounds like your display h/w is damaged!
PLZ try to boot with a rescue boot cd ( like hiren-boot-cd ) and see when you booting live-windows, do you have same problem??

( I told you a live windows because if it be a kernel fault ( that may be ) then if you use another lin. distro it have no diff. but you could first try another lin. live-cd and if the problems does not go just notice me to tell you how you could make sure it is/is not a hardware failure )

goodluck!

Comment: I had same problem with my last notebook because my monitor disp. got damaged!